# Count by partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of rows(fruits) in a table, along with the basic details like fruit name, description color.

I want to know how many people viewed that product, how people liked it, etc...

This is what I tried but it is returning completely wrong numbers:

```
SELECT        
    vw.[Id], 
    vw.[Name],
    vw.[Color],
    -- This is returning 268 for id 1 but it supposed to be 134
    (COUNT(v.PublicImageViewId) OVER (PARTITION BY v.[publicImageId] )) AS [ViewCount], 
    -- This is returning 268 for id 1 but it supposed to be 2, both these counts are same and wrong
    (COUNT(u.PublicImageUpvoteId) OVER (PARTITION BY v.[publicImageId] )) AS [UpvoteCount]
FROM            
    [PublicImage] vw
LEFT JOIN 
    [PublicImageUpvote] u ON u.[PublicImageId] = vw.[PublicImageId]
LEFT JOIN 
    [PublicImageFavourite] f ON f.[PublicImageId] = vw.[PublicImageId]
LEFT JOIN 
    [PublicImageView] v ON v.PublicImageId = vw.[PublicImageId]
```

This might not be done like this or I'm doing blunder mistake.

All I wanted is for each product no of views, no of likes, no of favorites ...etc

---

Tables:

```
Public Image Table
PublicImageId: PK
name, color

PublicImageUpvote (same for PublicImageView, PublicImageFavourite)
PublicImageUpvoteId: PK
PublicImageId: FK
CreatedBy, Created Date
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Use `count(distinct)` with `group by`. The analytic count is. not what you want. The number of rows will be the product of votes, views, and favorites.

Comment: can you please show me through the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `GROUP BY vw.[Id], vw.[Name], vw.[Color]` and count the distinct values:

```
SELECT        
    vw.[Id], 
    vw.[Name],
    vw.[Color],
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.PublicImageViewId) AS [ViewCount], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT u.PublicImageUpvoteId) AS [UpvoteCount]
FROM [PublicImage] vw
LEFT JOIN [PublicImageUpvote] u ON u.[PublicImageId] = vw.[PublicImageId]
LEFT JOIN [PublicImageFavourite] f ON f.[PublicImageId] = vw.[PublicImageId]
LEFT JOIN [PublicImageView] v ON v.PublicImageId = vw.[PublicImageId]
GROUP BY vw.[Id], vw.[Name], vw.[Color]
```

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest that you need another table for this

> How many people viewed that product, how people liked it, etc...

Then use `JOIN`

Comment: may I suggest you look at the other answers which people are providing and learn from them. If you are just going to offer tips on how to maybe solve the problem, then that belongs in a comment. An answer should fully answer the question that the OP is asking.